# Metro App OnNavigatedTo setting textbox value in a different method

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro

I am following around on a kindle book I bought for developing metro apps.  For some reason I cannot set the text value of a text box in a method outside the OnNavigatedTo method.  This is the code that the book provides:

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        //passed in the view model
        viewModel = e.Parameter as ViewModel;
        this.DataContext = viewModel;

        viewModel.PropertyChanged += (sender, eventArgs) =>
        {
            if (eventArgs.PropertyName == "SelectedItemIndex")
            {
                if (viewModel.SelectedIndex == -1)
                {
                    SetItemDetail(null);
                }
                else
                {
                    SetItemDetail(viewModel.GroceryList[viewModel.SelectedIndex]);
                }
            }
            SetItemDetail(viewModel.GroceryList[viewModel.SelectedIndex]);
        };
    }

    private void SetItemDetail(GroceryItem item)
    {
        ItemDetailName.Text = "test"; //(item == null) ? "" : item.Name;
        ItemDetailQuantity.Text = "test"; //(item == null) ? "" : item.Quantity.ToString();

        //if (item != null)
        //{
        //    ItemDetailStore.SelectedItem = item.Store;
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    ItemDetailStore.SelectedIndex = -1;
        //}
    }
```

I have commented parts out in the set item detail method, but I still cannot set the value of a textbox when I click it (this is supposed to be the behavior).  I have used break points and the property of the textbox is getting set, however, it is not displayed on screen.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post some XAML so we can get a better idea of how it all fits together?

Comment: do you have 100% that method where you want to set the Text is invoked ?